# wxpython sorting multiple listctrls

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I'm having trouble sorting multiple listctrls in wxpython.  I can sort one but not another.  I assume it all circles around the ColumnSorterMixin requirement for a function called GetListCtrl.  That function can only return one listctrl otherwise and index error will occur as it will only sort the last returned listctrl.  Is there a way around this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the `ColumSorterMixin` when creating the class that is a parent of the listctrls, like in the demo, and putting multiple listctrls on the parent. If you instead use it as one of the base classes when deriving a new `ListCtrl` class then `GetListCtrl` can just return self, and each listctrl will then have its own sorter.